# Expose ASP.NET Identity via LDAP interface (.NET Core 2.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ldap, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application where I am using the stock implementation of ASP.NET Identity to manage and authenticate my users.

I would like to use my application as an identity provider for 3rd party service that I am planning on using. The only issue is that this service can only communicate with identity providers over LDAP.

Is there a way to stand up an LDAP server as part of my ASP.NET Core application?

I know there is an option to do so in Java by using [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.ldap.com/unboundid-ldap-sdk-for-java). However, I cannot find a .NET alternative to this.

How should I go about exposing my ASP.NET Identity users via LDAP?